# How to configurate APP icon for Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox-os

my manifest.webapp:

```
"icons": {
    "30": "img/icon_30.png",
    "60": "img/icon_60.png"
},
```

but icon don't display in Firefox OS simulator. My app hosted on the Github Pages. I suspect that icon display in the simulator if the domain must be top-level domain.

Please give me a correct config example if my domain no problem. thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the whole path for the icon, from the root of your project. For example, if the folder for your project is called "hello_world" (so your GitHub project is http://github.com/user/hello_world), you'd write:

```
"icons": {
    "30": "/hello_world/img/icon_30.png",
    "60": "/hello_world/img/icon_60.png"
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But what `launch_path` should be?

Comment: `launch_path` should be something like `/hello_world/`

Comment: It's work! Thank you! But I must add manifest.webapp not URL.

Comment: That works for me in Mac OS X Yosemite and in the Firefox Emulator but it doesn't work in Windows. Please see this follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882910/how-to-specify-icons-for-firefox-hosted-app-in-windows